# How to gentrate Unique Id in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I am new to ReactJS. I want to use Unique Id in my react program. So I create a custom hook and that hook returns a unique id. But my situation is that when I use this custom hook in my component, at the same time my component was initialized twice. I don't know how to avoid multiple initial loads.

This is my custom Hook

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

export const CreateUniqueId = () => {
  const [renderId, forceUpdate] = useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);

  useEffect(() => {
    forceUpdate();
  }, []);

  return renderId;
};
```

If you know the answer, tell me what I should do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To generate a Unique ID you can use the uuid npm package for that  here is the link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I need to generate a Unique ID without any packages.

Answer (score 0):

Then, here that function that generate UUID

```js
    function uuidv4() {
        return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
            (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` and `getTime` straight into your components to get unique IDs on render:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const UniqueComponent = () => {
  const uniqueId = useState(new Date().getTime().toString())

  return (<div id={uniqueId}></div>)
};
```